# Project Tango MeasureIt Stops

Tags: google-project-tango

I installed the `MeasureIt` demo and then updated the `Project Tango Core` to its latest version because MeasureIt told incompatible Tango Core version and wanted me to update it. However now that I want to open the MeasureIt app, I receive `Unfortunately, Measure It has stopped` message. Any idea what could be wrong and how can it be fixed?

I am using `Project Tango Development Kit` Powered by Nvidia Tegra tablet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had experienced the same thing today.
The problem was resolved just by updating the Tango System.
You can do that by going to **Settings > About tablet > System updates** to install an available update.
The battery must be at least 25% charged to begin the update.
I hope this works for you as well.